# Execute parent process before child process or vice versa

Tags: c, process, fork, child-process

**Edit: I have modified the question to make it clearer.**

I want either:

1. Parent process modifies array, then child process displays updated array.

or

2. Child process modifies array, then parent process displays updated array.

This is the code for the first scenario. The child process does not display the updated array but the original array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    int p;
    int i;
    int values[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    p = fork();
    if (p != 0){
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            values[i] = values[i] * 100;
        }
    }else{
        printf("Updated elements: ");
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            printf("%d ", values[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure it is. Use a semaphore.

Comment: I was gonna suggest what Olaf did. Here is an example of semaphore: http://www.amparo.net/ce155/sem-ex.html

Comment: If I want to do the opposite, i.e. the parent process modifies the array, then the child process accesses the updated array, is a semaphore still required?

Comment: If it is only for testing, just put a sleep(1) after the fork in child or parent (whichever should run second).

Comment: Semaphores are good, Saiyan, but there are approaches where you could use what I suggested on my answer, the Polling method.

Comment: @Aleksandrus actually you described a kind of semaphore (which is more a general concept)

Comment: The parent process has already started executing. So do you want the parent to *pause* until the child process finishes?

Comment: @immibis

Yes, or the other way around. I want to make one process wait so that it can afterwards access the updated array.

Comment: NONE of this matters!  Unless he uses something (`mmap`) to share the array, the parent & child have separate arrays and neither can see changes made by the other!

Answer (score 0):

Use a [semaphore](http://www.csc.villanova.edu/~mdamian/threads/posixsem.html). Or, if you want something more simple (but at the cost of performance) you could have a `int* parentWait = 1;` and pass it to the child process. When the child finishes the process, it can update the content of `parentWait` to 0.

Then, on the parent's process, you could have

```
while(parentWait){
  // do nothing.
}
```

Though beware that, as pointed out by [Ctx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5636775/ctx), this approach would require the pointer `parentWait` to be pointing to a [shared map](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html). So, I'd recommend you to use the POSIX semaphore.

Comment: Except that memory isn't shared with `fork`.

Comment: @immibis He may have set up shared mappings before the fork()

Comment: I use pthreads and it works fine. Never used fork. So, would this solution not work?

Comment: It wouldn't work because the parent and child processes would have separate `parentWait` variables. The child would set its one to 0. The parent's would still be 1.

Comment: Oh, alright. I'll edit this answer then. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: @Ctx Not if you use `int* parentWait=1;`. In fact I'm assuming `int*` is a typo for `int`, because otherwise why would you write `int* parentWait=1;`?

Comment: @immibis Correct, I read it as pseudocode meaning "Setting some integer-pointer-target to 1". Should better be `volatile int *parentWait = mmap(...); *parentwait = 1; while (*parentwait);` etc.

Comment: @Ctx why don't you write an answer? You have a deeper knowledge than I in this matter

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not possible without the use of shared memory.
When you `fork()` the child gets a copy of the parent's memory (including the array).  However, there are now two different arrays, and neither process can see changes the other makes to their copy.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sched _yield()` syscall in parent context just after fork it will execute child first before parent process

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in the parent:  `waitpid(p, 0, 0);`

It's also better if you check for all three conditions instead of using (p != 0) since there are three possible outputs to the fork() call:

```
if ( p == 0 )  
// Child Code  
else if ( p > 0 )  
// Parent Code  
else  
   printf("fork failed");
```

As for executing parent first, it's usually not a good idea since it creates an orphan process. The child must terminate before the parent. You could do the code you want to execute before the child process before the fork() call. If you still want to execute parent first for some reason, you could use this in the child:
      `waitpid(getppid(), 0, 0);`
libraries:
`#include <sys/types.h>`
`#include <unistd.h>`
`#include<sys/wait.h>`